# Create a function which returns french date or english date

Tags: python, date

I have created a function `language` which returns `English` or `French`. I would like to create a function that would give the date now based on a select language. For instance, if I select `French`, the function will return `Jeudi, 28 mars 2017` or if I select `English`, it will return `Tuesday March 28 2017`.

```
@property
def date_customerprofile(self):
    now = datetime.date.today()
    if language == 'English'
        date = now.strftime("%A, %B %d %Y")
    else:
        date = ...
```

Could anyone be able to help me to finish this function to get such results?

Thanks!

**P.S.** Knowing that months in French are `Janvier`, `Février`, `Mars`, `Avril`, `Mai`, `Juin`, `Juillet`, `Août`, `Septembre`, `Octobre`, `Novembre` and `Décembre`. Days of week are `Dimanche` (Sunday), `Lundi`, `Mardi`, `Mercredi`, `Jeudi`, `Vendredi` and `Samedi`

Comment: The `datetime` module works in more than one locale. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4083447/355230) for an example showing weekday names in two languages (see the code at the end).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have required locale installed on your system.
For ubuntu to install french locale, run below command.

```
$ sudo locale-gen fr_FR.utf8
```

Below is the solution for the question

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale

def set_locale(locale_):
    locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale=locale_)


def date_customerprofile(language):
    now_ = datetime.today()
    if language == 'English':
        set_locale('en_US.utf8')
        date_ = now_.strftime("%A %B %d %Y")
    else:
        set_locale('fr_FR.utf8')
        date_ = now_.strftime("%A %B %d %Y")
    return date_
```

P.S. Avoid using standard package/function names as variables

Comment: I am working with a programmer's team. So I don't know if it is appropriate just to load `sudo locale-gen fr_FR.utf8`. I am working in a django project. What are you suggest?

Comment: Locale is OS dependent. Python is making use of it. To make use of it one needs to install required locale.